# Safari showing bookmarks from Google Chrome

Tags: safari, macos, data-synchronization, bookmarks

I've only recently just started using Safari, mainly to separate my personal accounts from my work accounts. As such, I've logged into Gmail in safari for one of my email accounts. I spent a while setting up bookmarks, configuring toolbars, etc.

I've just updated my MacBook Pro to 10.11.3, and suddenly Safari is showing all of my Chrome bookmarks, mixed in with the Safari ones I set up earlier.

I'm not logged into iCloud, I can't find anything in preferences to suggest syncing the bookmarks, and a quick google even leads me to suggest that it's not trivial to do so!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same happen to me, and likewise I prefer to keep my work and personal bookmarks separate. I was searching through menus and preferences when I noticed the **small pop-up message at the bottom of the Favorites page display that asked something like "Favorites showing bookmarks and recently visited from Google Chrome. [Keep] or [Do Not Keep]" so I clicked on Do Not Keep and it all went away.**

I don't like not being able to undo something, so I was looking for where in the settings or preferences this could be toggled, but alas no luck so I guess it's permanent.